# Multiple local repositories with same origin GIT

Tags: eclipse, git

I was trying to dig into some more complex git functionalities.

I'm using fork to interface with git branch management, Eclipse (Maven build tool) as my IDE and DBeaver for queries.

At the moment i often need to switch between branches which implies:

- Stash (if local changes available)
- Switch branch.
- Terminating JBOSS on eclipse
- Cleaning the project
- Restart the server
- Hoping the two branches does not have too many differences on the database side (otherwise i'd need a refresh)
- Losing my flow of thoughts while developing because of the topic change

I was trying to overcome all this cumbersome operations.

**What i did so far:**

- Created another instance of my local database to handle different data structures between branches
- I copied my workspace to change maven build properties to point another database. My **D:** folder contains both **WorkspaceA**,**WorkspaceB** (where B is simply the result of Ctrl-c Ctrl-v of the A)

The problem comes when having to deal with branches and origin. I may have some confusion.

**What i'd like to have**

- Two instances of Eclipse opened at the same time for the two different workspaces (**WorkspaceA, WorkspaceB**) --> Should be ok so far
- Two fork instances (one for each repositoriy inside each Workspace, **repositoryA**,**repositoryB** --> When creating new repository on the secon fork instance the issue is **the selected path is already a git repository**
- Basically the possibility to have two local repositories pointing to the same origin (like being two devs with their local repositories). I'd like to be on **BRANCH1** in my **RepositoryA** with my local changes and at the same time being on **BRANCH2** in my **RepositoryB** with other local changes.

Is this somehow making sense? Is there another solution to accomplish this task? What may be the major leaks in my reasonings? Thanks for your time.

Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you should just have the repository cloned in both workspaces (A and B) and work inside them independently.
This could look like:

- WorkspaceA/repository/
- WorkspaceB/repository/

Repositories in separate workspaces won't "know" about each other and therefore you can work with them independently and synchronize (pull/push) via origin.

Comment: So, if i understand i should clone again the origin/repository in another workspace? Because if i clone WorkspaceA/repository the cloned one will have as remote/origin repository the one in WorkspaceA and they will not point to the same origin but will make kind of a chain. Am i right?

Comment: @DavideBarbieri Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks i think that that was the step i was missing from all the logic. Cheers